# llenar input type text(html) despues de hacer post

Tags: php, html5, http-post

Hola a todos y feliz año lo primero. Estoy creando un formulario en html5, y necesito que después de hacer click en el botón submit y haga el proceso POST, rellene otro formulario, con los mismos datos que el anterior, por si ha habido algún error poder corregirlo antes de que se envíe definitivamente. Este es el código del formulario

```
<form action="fadaform020.php" method="get">
    Asociación: <input type="text" id="asociacion" value="$asociacion"/>
    Nick: <input type="text" id="jug_nickname" value="$nick"/>
    Nombre: <input type="text" id="jug_nombre"/>
    Apellidos: <input type="text" id="jug_apellidos"/>
    DNI: <input type="text" id="jug_dni"/>
    Fecha Nacimiento: <input type="text" id="jug_fec_nac"/>
    Email: <input type="text" id="jug_e_mail"/>
    Teléfono: <input type="text" id="jug_telefono"/>
    Duración: <input type="text" id="duracion_seguro"/>
    <input type="submit" id="enviar" onclick="rellenar();"/>
</form>
```

Este es el código desde el cual capturo el valor de los input que se han pasado por post:

```
$asociacion = $_POST['asociacion'];
$nick = $_POST['jug_nickname'];
$nombre = $_POST['jug_nombre'];
$apellidos = $_POST['jug_apellidos'];
$dni = $_POST['jug_dni'];
$fechaNacimiento = $_POST['jug_fec_nac'];
$email = $_POST['jug_e_mail'];;
$telefono = $_POST['jug_telefono'];
$duracion = $_POST['duracion_seguro'];
$comprobar_dni = comprobar_documento_identificacion($dni);
```

He leido que se puede hacer con javascript, pero nunca he tocado ese lenguaje y no se como se hace, a parte de que yo necesito rellenarlo, una vez se ha enviado el formulario.

gracias de antemano y un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando $_GET:

```
$asociacion = $_GET['asociacion'];
$nick = $_GET['jug_nickname'];
$nombre = $_GET['jug_nombre'];
$apellidos = $_GET['jug_apellidos'];
$dni = $_GET['jug_dni'];
$fechaNacimiento = $_GET['jug_fec_nac'];
$email = $_GET['jug_e_mail'];;
$telefono = $_GET['jug_telefono'];
$duracion = $_GET['duracion_seguro'];
$comprobar_dni = comprobar_documento_identificacion($dni);
```

Comment: gracias, pero $_GET van los datos en abierto por URL y no me interesa. ya lo he solucionado. Es así value="<?php echo $asociacion; ?>

Comment: Ok, suerte entonces con tu projecto